# Phoenix unique_constraint error while trying to build database

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am following along with Phoenix 1.4 book, and I got to "Using the Repository Data" section when I tried to put in data into through the terminal to the database I got an error.

My IEx session:

```
iex(1)> alias Rumbl.Repo
Rumbl.Repo
iex(2)> alias Rumbl.Accounts.User
Rumbl.Accounts.User
iex(3)> Repo.insert(%User{
...(3)> name: "José", username: "josevalim"
...(3)> })
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=16.7ms queue=1.2ms
INSERT INTO "users" ("name","username","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id" ["José", "josevalim", ~N[2018-11-24 11:47:30], ~N[2018-11-24 11:47:30]]
```

It threw the following error:

```
** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * users_username_index (unique_constraint)

If you would like to stop this constraint violation from raising an
exception and instead add it as an error to your changeset, please
call `unique_constraint/3` on your changeset with the constraint
`:name` as an option.

The changeset has not defined any constraint.

    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:641: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1314: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:626: Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:238: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/3
```

Comment: The error is indicating that you already have a row in the database with that name and username. What do you get when your run `Repo.all(User)` or `Repo.get_by(User, name: "José", username: "josevalim")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It seems that you have created a [unique index](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.0/Ecto.Migration.html#index/3) in your `users` table migration**.

The constraint is on your `username` key meaning two records in the `users` table cannot have the same username. In your case, that means you have already created another user in the table with the username `josevalim`.

---

To get Ecto to return `{:error, changeset}` tuple instead of raising an error, you can tell the schema that there's a [**unique constraint**](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3) in your `changeset/2` method:

```ex
def changeset(user, params) do
  user
  |> cast(params, [:name, :username])
  |> validate_required([:name, :username])
  |> unique_constraint(:username, name: :users_username_index)
end
```

And use this method to build a changeset before inserting anything:

```ex
%User{}
|> changeset(%{name: "José", username: "josevalim"})
|> Repo.insert
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that the `:name` option must match the name of the index that Ecto generated.